# Where are good abdominal places for measuring SO2 and heart rate via reflective pulse oximeter?

Tags: blood, measurement, abdominal, pulse-oximeter

I'm trying to develop a belt (wearable device) from which I could measure belly stretch (exhalation, inhalation), heart pulse frequency and blood oxygen saturation data via optical EKG (reflective method). I have chosen this method since its cheaper than developing sensors for measuring the electrical pulse of a heart. And because I want to create a belt which a user could wear I need to know if it's even possible to get heart rate readings from the abdominal region.

As I'm aware there are only finger oximeters and some [proof of concept oximeters for neck/wrist devices](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/320117416_Pulse_oximetry_in_the_neck_-_a_proof_of_concept), but I could not find any device that would get readings from the abdominal region.

So what are some good places in the abdominal region that I could get valid and accurate readings for heart rate, SO2 and at the same time breathing status?

Comment: I think you're going to be hard pressed to get accurate pulse and SpO2 readings from the abdomen, especially in people with significant abdominal fat.

Comment: Heh I didn't think about that xD. Thank you!